# SQL request excluding periods of time

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, right-to-left, period

I need to get all DISTINCT users excluding those who are not available according to unavailability periods of time.

The `user` table:

```
+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | firstname | content                              |
+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| 13   | John      | ...                                  |
| 44   | Marc      | ...                                  |
| 55   | Elise     | ...                                  |
+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

The `unavailability` periods table:

```
+------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| id   | user_id   | start        | end          |
+------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1    | 13        | 2019-07-01   | 2019-07-10   |
| 2    | 13        | 2019-07-20   | 2019-07-30   |
| 3    | 13        | 2019-09-01   | 2019-09-30   |
| 4    | 44        | 2019-08-01   | 2019-08-15   |
+------+-----------+--------------+--------------|
```

For example, we want user who are available from 2019-06-20 to 2019-07-05: Marc and Elise are available.

Do I have to use a LEFT JOIN? This request is not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.*, unavailability.start, unavailability.end,
FROM user
LEFT JOIN unavailability ON unavailability.user_id = user.id
WHERE  
unavailability.start < "2019-06-20" AND unavailability.end > "2019-06-20"
AND unavailability.start < "2019-07-05" AND unavailability.end > "2019-07-05"
```

And I need as result:

```
+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | firstname | content                              |
+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| 44   | Marc      | ...                                  |
| 55   | Elise     | ...                                  |
+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

With this request I don't get Elise who has no unavailability periods of time.

Comment: What would the desired result actually look like? Edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Strawberry It says so above the example query.

Comment: You do realise that the dates need quotes around them? (it's probably just a typo in the question).

Comment: I have edited the question. @KIKOSoftware I had forgotten the quotes in my request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the ids of the *unavailables* and use this result in a subquery :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(5),
  `content` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO user
  (`id`, `firstname`, `content`)
VALUES
  (13, 'John', '...'),
  (44, 'Marc', '...'),
  (55, 'Elise', '...');



CREATE TABLE unavailability (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `start` DATETIME,
  `end` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO unavailability
  (`id`, `user_id`, `start`, `end`)
VALUES
  (1, 13, '2019-07-01', '2019-07-10'),
  (2, 13, '2019-07-20', '2019-07-30'),
  (3, 13, '2019-09-01', '2019-09-30'),
  (4, 44, '2019-08-01', '2019-08-15');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM user us
WHERE us.id NOT IN (
  SELECT u.user_id
  FROM unavailability u
  WHERE u.start <= '2019-07-05' AND u.end >= '2019-06-20'
);

| id  | firstname | content |
| --- | --------- | ------- |
| 44  | Marc      | ...     |
| 55  | Elise     | ...     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jVY7tT8bPXJLtrcz44CKR/0)

---

**Note**

This condition :

```
unavailability.start < 2019-06-20 AND unavailability.end > 2019-06-20
AND unavailability.start < 2019-07-05 AND unavailability.end > 2019-07-05
```

Will be evaluated like this :

```
unavailability.start < 2019-06-20 AND unavailability.end > 2019-07-05
```

Because, for the parts `unavailability.start < 2019-06-20 AND unavailability.start < 2019-07-05`, everything below `2019-07-05` but above `2019-06-20` will be excluded (you are using `AND`). The same for both `unavailability.end`

Comment: Didn't know db-fiddle.com really cool :) Thanks for the note... `unavailability.start < 2019-06-20  AND unavailability.start < 2019-07-05` is a bit silly ! :P

Comment: But only Elise is available from `01-01-2019` to `12-31-2019` and we get the 3 users: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8t3n2YNKyF3ws8KADMCDQ8/0

Comment: available from date1 to date2 is written start <= date2 and end >= date1. Check this [updated fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8t3n2YNKyF3ws8KADMCDQ8/1) (You've inverted the dates)

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;

CREATE TABLE user

(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,firstname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO user VALUES
(13,'John'),
(44,'Marc'),
(55,'Elise');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unavailability ;

CREATE TABLE unavailability 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,start DATE NOT NULL
,end DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO unavailability VALUES
(1,13,'2019-07-01','2019-07-10'),
(2,13,'2019-07-20','2019-07-30'),
(3,13,'2019-09-01','2019-09-30'),
(4,44,'2019-08-01','2019-08-15');

SELECT x.* 
  FROM user x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN unavailability y 
    ON y.user_id = x.id 
   AND y.start <= '2019-07-05' 
   AND y.end >= '2019-06-20' 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+-----------+
| id | firstname |
+----+-----------+
| 44 | Marc      |
| 55 | Elise     |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Not working actually, only Elise is available for the period of time from `2019-01-01` to `2019-12-31` and I get the 3 users: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8t3n2YNKyF3ws8KADMCDQ8/0

Comment: Working fine actually. Your query differs from mine in some key respects.

Answer (score 2):

This approach can be used:

```
select * from user k
where not exists (
select 1 from user 
join unavailability u on u.user_id = user.id
and ('2019-06-20' between start and end or '2019-07-05' between start and end)
where user.id = k.id)
```